# AS3 Read JSON from PHP

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3

im sending json data from php to actionscript but i get this error

```
SyntaxError: Error #1132: Entrada de análisis JSON no válida.
    at JSON$/parseCore()
    at JSON$/parse()
    at Code.GUI.Menu::Biblioteca/urlLoaderCompleteHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

here its my action script code

```
package Code.GUI.Menu
{   
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class Biblioteca extends MovieClip
    {
        var urlLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();

        public function Biblioteca () :void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }

        public function init(event:Event){
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("test.php"));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderCompleteHandler);
        }
        function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
            trace(e.target.data) ;
            var arrayReceived:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
        }

    }

}
```

this is test.php

```
<?php 
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

this its waht the flash cs6 console show

```
<?php 
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
SyntaxError: Error #1132: Entrada de análisis JSON no válida.
    at JSON$/parseCore()
    at JSON$/parse()
    at Code.GUI.Menu::Biblioteca/urlLoaderCompleteHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

when i check with javascipt

```
$.getJSON('test.php',{format: "json"}, function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

it works! but actionscript seems to have problems with the sintax output

```
Object {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5…}
```

Comment: fixed! i needed to add the local host url in order to php to process it `urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888/test.php"));`

Comment: Please add your answer as a proper answer and accept it so other people can find it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed! i needed to add the local host url in order to php to process it 
`urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888/test.php"));`